# owlCarousel is not a function in rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, carousel

I have a rails app where I'm attempting to use an owl carousel to display a list of testimonials with images.  I think I have everything set up correctly, but I'm still receiving a console error that "owlCarousel is not a function".

I have installed the gemfile correctly.

`gemfile`

```
gem 'owlcarousel-rails'
```

I'm pretty sure I have everything loaded into application.js.
`app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails";
import "controllers";
import 'owl.carousel';

//= require_tree .
//= require jquery
//= require owl.carousel
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

Same with the application scss file:
`app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

```
@import "bulma";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "owl.carousel";
@import "../stylesheets/main/main.scss";

 *
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 *= require_self
 *= require owl.carousel
 */
```

This is my main view, where I have the carousel.
`app/views/main/index.html.erb`

```
<section class="testimonials-carousel-container">
  <div class="testimonials-carousel">
    <div id="owl-carousel">
      <div class="carousel-of-images">
        <div class="carousel-image">Item</div>
        <div class="carousel-image">Item</div>
        <div class="carousel-image">Item</div>
        <div class="carousel-image">Item</div>
        <div class="carousel-image">Item</div>
      </div>
      <div class="gradient-left"></div>
      <div class="gradient-right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The function that controls the carousel:
`app/assets/javascripts/testimonials.js`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

Lastly, I am importing the `testimonials.js` at the bottom of `app/views/main/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "testimonials" %>
```

I'm also noticing a ton of warnings in my JS output including the "owlCarousel is not a function" error.  I'm not sure if some of these other warnings are impacting this.

[image]

Comment: If you have turbo-rails, probably you use rails7. Therefore you don't need any gem for owl carousel, use native JS library instead. BTW last commit of owl carousel was in 2019. jquery_ujs is from rails4, turbo links are from rails6. Very strange set in 2023:)

Comment: "I think I have everything set up correctly" - nope. Rails 7 with importmaps - is what you have, start fresh, throw this set up away. I think `swiper` is the new carousel hotness. When looking up instructions, they have to be for rails 7, you can't just find a 10 year old blog post and expect it to work.